# How to pass Google OAuth 2 token to Azure API Authentication?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, google-oauth

I followed the steps here to hook up Google OAuth to Azure Authentication.  Unfortunately, those instructions stop very short of a full solution and don't mention what to do with the Google OAuth `access_token` once you have it.  I tried putting it into the Authorization header as a Bearer token (`Bearer <access_token>`), but that doesn't appear to work as my application sitting behind the Authorization service just sees the original Authorization header, not the expected `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME`, `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID`, `X-MS-TOKEN-GOOGLE-ACCESS-TOKEN`, etc.

Also, when I navigate to `/.auth/me` with an Authorization Bearer token I get a 401 response.

Sadly, all of the documentation is either specific to AD (which doesn't seem to apply to my scenario) or it is specific to server-side rendered applications, not SPAs that are hosted separate from the API they are calling.

An ideal answer would tell me what I need to do with the Google OAuth 2 `access_token` to get Azure authorization service to authenticate the token and add the expected headers.

Edit: The `access_token` is not a JWT token, which may be part of the problem.  If this is in fact the problem and I just need to get a JWT token then how do I do that?  I'm currently using the Google Client API JavaScript (beta).  I attempted to get a JWT token via the Google OAuth 2 dashboard but putting that as a Bearer token also didn't work, despite using my application's client secret to generate the requests.

Comment: How did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the access_token in the JSON body to '/.auth/login/google' with key as 'access_token'.

As explained in the following link:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/

Snippet from the above link:

"Alternatively, a client can obtain a token using a provider SDK and exchange it for a session token. Simply submit an HTTP POST to the same endpoint with the provider token in a JSON body under the key “access_token” (or “authenticationToken” for Microsoft Account). This is the preferred solution for mobile applications if a provider SDK is available on the platform, and it also works for many web and API applications."